# Timelapse App in PhoneGap

Tags: java, javascript, android, cordova

I have a simple question. Is it possible to make a simple app that takes a photo every 5 seconds, for instance?

capture.captureImage
camera.getPicture

Use standard Android camera app to take photo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, not with the standard API you'd need to write a plugin. The Camera.getPicture and Capture.captureImage commands require user interaction.